# Раздельная обработка выбора пунктов Spinner -ов, когда содержание одного зависит от позиции другого

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Есть 2  edittext, 2 spinner и кнопка с textview. Задумка вот какая. вводить 2 значения в edittext на одном спиннере выбрать допустим марку, а во втором размер и при нажатии кнопки все рассчитывало....

```
dlina = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dlina);
shirina = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shirina);
tip = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.tip);
razmer = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.razmer);
rasschet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rasschet);
otvet = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.otvet);

tip.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

rasschet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dlina.getText().toString())) {
            a = Integer.parseInt(dlina.getText().toString());
        } else {
             a = 0;
             if (dlina.getText().toString().length() == 0)
                 dlina.setError(getString(R.string.dlina));
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(shirina.getText().toString())) {
            b = Integer.parseInt(shirina.getText().toString());
        } else {
            b = 0;
            if (shirina.getText().toString().length() == 0)
                shirina.setError(getString(R.string.shirina));
        }

        d = a * b * c;
        otvet.setText(Integer.toString(d));
    }
});

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    String tips = String.valueOf(tip.getSelectedItem());
    pos = tip.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if (pos == 0) {
        c = 2;
    }
    if (pos == 1) {
        c = 4;
    }
    if (pos == 2) {
        c = 6;
    }
    //Toast.makeText(this, tips, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (tips.contentEquals("ballon")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("120,7 × 19,3");
        list.add("128,8 × 18,6");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        razmer.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

С таким кодом при нажатии кнопки получаю ответ т.к буква С в формуле забита под первый spinner, а мне надо что бы буква С в формуле реагировала на второй spinner в который я заношу размеры.... Подсобите граждане, ато вообще уже голову сломал... Заранее благодарен

Comment: Я нифига не понял. Но, кажется, вам надо просто разные обработчики на разные спиннеры повесить.

Comment: У меня первый спиннер - это марка, когда я выбрал любую марку на втором спиннере появляется размеры этой марки... так вот буква C из формулы в моем коде реагирует на спиннер с маркой, а мне нужно с размером

Comment: Ну так вы второму спиннеру нигде не назначили слушатель... Воспользуйтесь для второго спинера анонимным классом, создающимся прямо в методе-назначателе-слушателя. примерно так `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){...});`

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло....

Comment: вот только это все применяется для всех размеров. if (tips.contentEquals("ballon")) { я ведь в первом спиннере могу много марок создать и размеров на них могу закинуть куча. А применяется по позиционно для всех....как бы их разделить?

Comment: Я опять не очень вас понимаю. Вы убрали работу с `C` из обработчика первого спиннера?. Вам надо как-то так действовать: в первом спиннере по позиции создавать данные для второго спиннера, наполнять его адаптер и присваивать ему слушатель, в коем вы и должны с `C` работать..

Comment: да убрал и сделал обработчик во второй спиннкр.Все отлично работает. При нажатии дает отличный Ответ как и нужно...Я вот к чему. Я с первого спиннера(марка) передаю информацию во второй(размеры). Вот так: if (tips.contentEquals("ballon")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("120,7 × 19,3");
        list.add("128,8 × 18,6");

Comment: и таких я могу наделать сотни, но мой код во втором обработчике String razmers= String.valueOf(razmer.getSelectedItem());
     pos = razmer.getSelectedItemPosition();
     if (pos == 0) {
      c = 2;
     }
     if (pos == 1) {
      c = 4;
     } валит всеразмеры под одну гребенку...как бы мне их всех разделить?

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ. Если он (и комменты, на коих он основан) вам помогли, то надо отметить ответ как верный нажав на галочку слева от его тела. И в следующий раз старайтесь писать заголовок вопроса по аналогии с моей правкой заголовка текущего вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо разные спиннеры обрабатывать в разных обработчиках. Алгоритм должен быть примерно такой:

В обработчике первого спиннера при выборе элемента, по позиции:

1. создавать данные для второго спиннера
2. наполнять его адаптер и присваивать ему слушатель
3. в коем вы и должны переменную `C` заполнять данными.

   ```
   spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
   {
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
           {
               List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
               ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
               //тут по позиции создаёте данные для второго спиннера
               switch(position)
               {
                   case 0:
                   list.add("120,7 × 19,3");
                   list.add("128,8 × 18,6");

                   dataAdapter =
               new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                   dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   razmer.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                   //тут назначайте слушатель второму спиннеру.
                   break;

                   case 1:
                   //создавайте другие данные для другого типа
                   list.add("42 × 42");
                   list.add("over9000 × over9000 ");

                   dataAdapter =
               new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                   dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   razmer.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                   //тут назначайте слушатель второму спиннеру.
                   break;
           }

           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
           {

           }
       });
   ```